# PHP move_uploaded_file results in error #1

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, php-ini

I try to upload a file to an external server based on this code: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp .
On my local machine everything works fine but when uploading the exact same script to an external server it won't work anymore. When debugging with:

```
$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["error"]
```

I get an Error #1 in return altough im running the same php.ini as on my local machine. The `uploads/` folder exists and the user `www-data` has also permissions to write it. I proofed this by running `file_put_contents("uploads/test.txt", "working");`. The only thing I could think of is the PHP Version difference (Local: 7.2.5; External: 7.2.19) or maybe a missing php module?!

It would be great if someone could help me solving this.

Comment: Did you tried with full path?

Comment: Value: 1 means: The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini. What is the size of the file you are trying to upload? You might have to modify php.ini settings on the target machine.

Comment: @Andreas The value is set to 50M and the file I want to upload is only 2MB. Like I wrote it's working on my local machine with the **same** php.ini .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, i was dumb. I changed the wrong php.ini file. For anyone who experiences similar issues you can check the location of the php.ini file and if it's loaded by PHP with:

```
$inipath = php_ini_loaded_file();

if ($inipath) {
    echo 'Loaded php.ini: ' . $inipath;
} else {
    echo 'A php.ini file is not loaded';
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try with **full path** using [$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) also try to create **recursively** your folders using [mkdir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) with 3rd parameter set to `true` (if not exists your path), increments your `upload_max_filesize` as suggested by Andreas into comments... here is a pseudo working example...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
Upload File: <input type="file" size="30" id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload">
<?php
$upload_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/upload/var/www/html/";
if (!is_dir($upload_dir)) { 
  @mkdir($upload_dir, 0755, true);
}
if ((isset($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'])) && (!empty($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']))) {
  $temp_name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
  $file_name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
  $file_path = $upload_dir.$file_name;
  $upload_process = move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $file_path);
  @chmod($file_path,0755);
}
if ((isset($upload_process)) && ($upload_process == TRUE)) {
  echo "File Uploaded With Success...";
}
if ((!isset($upload_process)) || ($upload_process == FALSE)) {
  echo "Please, Upload some File...";
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

I hope this helps.